# сайт на html5 генерирует изображение внутри canvas. как его отправить на сервер vk.com?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5, vkontakte-api

я написал сайт на JavaScript  и HTML5. он генерирует изображение внутри canvas, и умеет сохранять их на компьютер. я хочу добавить кнопку - *поделиться в вконтакте*

я нашел js для шаринга контента http://vk.com/js/api/share.js , а еще 
у меня на сайте есть такой код для сохранения изображений

```js
function download() { //upload
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

но как связать это вместе я понять не смог.
прошу совета о реализации загрузки canvas в вк.
можно ли обойтись без php? что примерно гуглить и.т.п

есть такие мысли, но пока что я особо не имею идей что делать дальше

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // begin shape
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

  // complete custom shape
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();

  //Convert canvas image to URL format (base64)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  // Send it to server

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {
      imgBase64: dataURL
    }
  }).done(function(o) {
    console.log('saved');
  });
</script>
```

читаю это https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto

Answer (score 2):

Вы не сможете отправить во ВКонтакте какое-либо изображение (не важно, нарисованное на canvas или обычный jpeg-файл) с помощью JavaScript из-за ограничений CORS. Вы должны отправить изображение на свой сервер и сформировать запрос уже там.

Также хочу предупредить вас, что вы не сможете напрямую со своего сервера запостить изображение на стене пользователя. Приложения типа "веб-сайт" могут отправлять посты на стену только через Open API (перед публикацией поста у пользователя открывается окно подтверждения).

Ход действий должен быть таким:

1. Создайте альбом через сервер.
2. Загрузите в него картинку через сервер.
3. На вашем сайте с помощью Open API вызовите метод `wall.post`.